# Calculate div number with distance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a carousel like a casino roulette but i can't find the way to know which div number is when i make the animation. I'm trying to calculate by distance when i make the animation loop but i doesn't work

Here's my example

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXbpJr?page=1&

```
    var giftamount = 10;
var gw = $('.gift').outerWidth(true);
var giftcenter = gw/2;
var cycle = 7;

var containercenter = $('.boxwrapper').outerWidth(true)/2;
for(var i = 0; i <=5; i++)
{
  var giftduplicate = $('.giftwrapper').children().clone(true,true);
   $('.giftwrapper').append(giftduplicate);   
}    

$('.button').click(function(){
  var btn = $(this);
  btn.hide();
  var randomgift = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var distance = giftamount * gw * cycle + containercenter + (randomgift*gw) - giftcenter;

  console.log(distance);

  $( ".giftwrapper" ).css({left: "0"});

  $('.giftwrapper').animate({left: "-="+distance},10000,function(){
    alert('You Won Gift' + randomgift); 
    btn.show();                  
   });
});
```

i get the wrong number of div, i tried a lot of combination but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you try to be more specific what the problem is? I think it's just the wording. Are you trying to see which Prize box you landed on?

Comment: I assume that the prize won is the one underneath the pointer (the vertical red line)?

Comment: @Terry that definitely is the prize that you won but I am trying to understand if the problem is actually in determining that, considering the alert contains a different value. I am asking for clarification to the question but also questioning the logic.

Comment: No worries :) I am writing my answer now, already have a working solution.

Comment: @Terry sounds good - I have working code in production too since this is a popular dynamic for many CS:GO case opening sites but my implementation doesn't rely on any calculations on the UI elements and instead it creates/deletes elements dynamically with the prize it lands on being predefined - very much the same way CS:GO does it. It is just too risky to be determining an actual prize based on something that happens client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and substitute this for the `distance`

```
var distance = giftamount *  cycle * gw   + (randomgift*gw) - containercenter -24;
```

The idea is the following: with `distance=- containercenter;` you would move to be left-aligned with the center of the container.
To that you add a certain number of cycles `giftamount *  cycle * gw` and finally a random number of gift elements (`(randomgift*gw)`).

I *could not* figure out where the constant `-24` comes from. I hard-coded and it needs to be better defined but I guess it might depend on some margins/approximations/jQuery/CSS/??

Now you should see that the animation always stops at the same point within the gift element (in the middle). To add a random deviation you could ad a small deviation `dev` (that lets you stay within the gift element) like this:

```
var dev = Math.random()*(giftcenter+1);
var distance = giftamount *  cycle * gw   + (randomgift*gw) - containercenter -24 +dev;
```

Updated demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLNeBX

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the prize that is underneath the pointer (the vertical red bar), you actually do not have to compute the distance. Instead, you can make use of a really handy but somewhat less known DOM API method known as [`elementFromPoint(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint), where you can obtain a reference to the **topmost** DOM node under the x,y coordinate of the page.

In order for this to work, `x` and `y` will have to correspond to the **visual center of the pointer**, which can we can simply calculate by using:

```
var $pointer = $('.rafflebox .pointer');
var pointerX = $pointer.offset().left + $pointer.width() * 0.5;
var pointerY = $pointer.offset().top + $pointer.height() * 0.5;
```

In jQuery's animation callback, you simply can retrieve the element (aka the prize) underneath this coordinate:

```
// Hide pointer first, otherwise it will be returned as the topmost element
$pointer.hide();

// Get element from pointer's visual center
var prize = document.elementFromPoint(pointerX, pointerY);

// Show it again
$pointer.show();
```

Now you have the correct reference to the DOM node, it is up to you to decide what kind of metadata you want to store in the "prize" DOM node. For example, you can embed a HTML5 data- attribute in your HAML:

```
%img{:src => "http://placehold.it/125x125?text=Prize+#{i}", :data => {:prize => "Prize #{i}"}}
```

...which simply stores the text `Prize (n)` (where `n` is the prize number) in the attribute `data-prize`, and we can access it later using:

```
var prize = document.elementFromPoint(pointerX, pointerY);
console.log($(prize).data('prize'));
```

---

When we replace part of your code with what I have suggested, you get this:

```
  // Get visual center of pointer
  var $pointer = $('.rafflebox .pointer');
  var pointerX = $pointer.offset().left + $pointer.width() * 0.5;
  var pointerY = $pointer.offset().top + $pointer.height() * 0.5;

  $( ".giftwrapper" ).css({left: "0"});

  $('.giftwrapper').animate({left: "-="+distance},10000,function(){
    // Hide pointer first, otherwise it will be returned as the topmost element
    $pointer.hide();

    // Get element from pointer's visual center
    var prize = document.elementFromPoint(pointerX, pointerY);

    // Show it again
    $pointer.show();
    alert('You Won Gift ' + $(prize).data('prize')); 
    btn.show();                  
   });
```

Here is your updated pen with a working example: https://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/dVPdMg

---

### Updated example

There is a very small chance that the pointer will land **in between prizes**. To prevent this, you will want to use `padding` instead of `margin` on the `.gift` element:

```
.gift {
    // Change margin to padding
    padding: 0px 4px;
}
```

...and perform additional checks on the returned `prize` node:

```
// Hide pointer first, otherwise it will be returned as the topmost element
$pointer.hide();

// Get element from pointer's visual center
var $prize = $(document.elementFromPoint(pointerX, pointerY));

// If prize lands on the .gift element instead
if(!$prize.is('img'))
    $prize = $prize.find('img')

// Show it again
$pointer.show();
alert('You Won Gift' + $prize.data('prize')); 
btn.show();
```

The pen here is simply a fork of the original solution, but with exaggerated horizontal padding to increase the chance of the pointer landing in between iamges: https://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/rGaJmY

Comment: It is worth noting that this value should not be trusted since it's possible for anyone to simply modify the `data-prize` attribute of any of the elements client-side.